# Remove invisible Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again alert

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I'm using invisible reCaptcha but I get the error alert " Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again alert" when I click recaptcha several times. How do I remove this error and allow for several clicks on my reCaptcha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue yesterday. Most likely you either have the wrong site key or you are hiding the badge on your page.

Comment: Not the problem for me